# Missing separate debuginfo for - GDB

Tags: linux, opensuse, software-installation, debugging, gdb

I have mentioned `-g` option along with `-Wall` in the `Makefile`.

When I run `gdb onlineSunday`, I get:

```
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/kde4/plugins/imageformats/kimg_dds.so
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=a84a1969b9a69361b10f26814c0958717c48d671"
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/kde4/plugins/imageformats/kimg_eps.so
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=81e00b39aa9b3f7af23bad9d5bcef9f7cfe6333e"
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/kde4/plugins/imageformats/kimg_exr.so
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=0101355f5aa48dca9cf2723c94d1a4b7eb21e2ec"
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libIlmImf.so.6
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=f26997841c2902a0db04726d4018640cf367101e"
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libIex.so.6
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=2af205c15500875184d2b8519dbe01404bdfb3ae"
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libHalf.so.6
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=5134d1c2dc3c6ea90b5eeabd518eb746c853b87c"
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libIlmThread.so.6
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=ebb1d12661df5bbf0dd39c7c717cd197ada35d98"
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/kde4/plugins/imageformats/kimg_jp2.so
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=c1c25e24a14a9ec9163d623c699b6b53b7a1aabc"
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libjasper.so.1
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=d521bb2892ccef13f28afaa82c0ef48433e46ca5"
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=c3638afbf013f8e33beaa3dc12f4d2dbdb3f8602"
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/kde4/plugins/imageformats/kimg_pcx.so
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=d1b443e7a29dd71a2519d852057c814bcfc9c30b"
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/kde4/plugins/imageformats/kimg_pic.so
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=4d533a04cab4426beaf2ae3c89eb2e026e5e1f81"
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/kde4/plugins/imageformats/kimg_psd.so
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=39ff79c31ae413ebac40eb8baef54ac524886e57"
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/kde4/plugins/imageformats/kimg_ras.so
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=7ecf3f8738c8cfacb14b6e54b53526346513dc8b"
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/kde4/plugins/imageformats/kimg_rgb.so
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=fc5d771438bc73014a4d551eb3b996043729c625"
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/kde4/plugins/imageformats/kimg_tga.so
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=9dd675ab0b9906bb234a90f8f4e9e65b7b6fbf63"
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/kde4/plugins/imageformats/kimg_xcf.so
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=2bfe0932ffdf6473010f792e1bde388881fdaff0"
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/kde4/plugins/imageformats/kimg_xview.so
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=6ba5f69301b600fe14553d99ef495df1d08ba379"
"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: displayMapAndClick on line:1 Source:undefined" 
Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/libnss_files.so.2
```

**GDB version:**

```
anisha@linux-trra:~> gdb -version
GNU gdb (GDB) SUSE (7.2-3.3)

anisha@linux-trra:~>
```

**The package:**

```
linux-trra:~ # cnf debuginfo-install

Program 'debuginfo-install' is present in package 'yum-utils', which is installed on your system.

Absolute path to 'debuginfo-install' is '/usr/bin/debuginfo-install'. Please check your $PATH variable to see whether it contains the mentioned path.

linux-trra:~ #
```

**The system:**

```
linux-trra:~ # cat /etc/issue && uname -a
Welcome to openSUSE 11.4 "Celadon" - Kernel \r (\l).

Linux linux-trra 2.6.37.1-1.2-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT 2011-02-21 10:34:10 +0100 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

linux-trra:~ #
```

**This is what I did:**

```
linux-trra: # zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=a84a1969b9a69361b10f26814c0958717c48d671"
Retrieving repository 'Updates for openSUSE 11.4 11.4-0' metadata [done]
Building repository 'Updates for openSUSE 11.4 11.4-0' cache [done]
Retrieving repository 'devel:languages:R:patched' metadata [done]
Building repository 'devel:languages:R:patched' cache [done]
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
No provider of 'debuginfo(build-id) = a84a1969b9a69361b10f26814c0958717c48d671' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.

linux-trra: #
```

**What to do now?**

---

```
linux-trra: # zypper ar -f -n "openSUSE-11.4-Debug" http://download.opensuse.org/debug/distribution/11.4/repo/oss/ repo-debug
Adding repository 'openSUSE-11.4-Debug' [done]
Repository named 'repo-debug' already exists. Please use another alias.

linux-trra: # zypper ar -f -n "openSUSE-11.4-Debug" http://download.opensuse.org/debug/distribution/11.4/repo/oss/ repo-debug-update
Adding repository 'openSUSE-11.4-Debug' [done]
Repository named 'repo-debug-update' already exists. Please use another alias.

linux-trra: #
```

Comment: Libraries you are using are not built with debug flag enabled.You'll need debug info for those libraries.

Comment: @perilbrain so, what am I supposed to do now? Elaborate please.

Comment: See if this can help http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/427318-missing-separate-debuginfo.html

Answer (score 3):

You can debug a program even if not all the libraries have debuginfo, you just won't be able to follow into the library in terms of source code. Most of the time the problems aren't in the library anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Enable and refresh the debug repos.

http://download.opensuse.org/debug/distribution/11.4/repo/oss/

http://download.opensuse.org/debug/update/11.4/

```
 zypper ar -f -n "openSUSE-11.4-Debug" http://download.opensuse.org/debug/distribution/11.4/repo/oss/ repo-debug
 zypper ar -f -n "openSUSE-11.4-Update-Debug" http://download.opensuse.org/debug/update/11.4/ repo-debug-update
```

EDIT:
After you've enabled the repos, then you should be able to install your packages.